# Convert Number in Java

Tags: java, powerbuilder

How to round a number in Java?

- Input: `0.655308`; Expected output: `65.53`.
- Input: `1.0583104`; Expected output: `105.83`.

In power builder compute expression I use

```
 act_qty  *work_hour /
 if (on_hour < work_hour )  /
  sec_setm_gole_qty ,4)
```

How to run it in Java?

Comment: You can literally just `String.format("%.2f",value*100)+"%"`

Answer (score 1):

I would just multiply the value with 100

```
double roundedValue = value * 100;
System.out.printf("%.2f", roundedValue);
```

Comment: `printf`, not `prinf`

Comment: ahh yeaa, thank you! hahaha

Answer (score 0):

`String.format("%.2f%%",value*100)`?

Comment: Minor tweak: ```String.format("%.2f%%",value*100)```.  If you're using .format you might as well have it produce the whole string, rather than concatenating a percent sign on after formatting.

Comment: It was that easy to get a literal % into a format string?